# Find custom elements in webdriver

Tags: webdriver, selenium-webdriver

Why aren't [custom tags](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/customelements/) supported yet in Selenium WebDriver? I realise the W3C web components proposal is still under review, but browsers are already implementing them widely (angular apps come to mind e.g. `ng-app`).

Comment: Can you please give example of custom element?

Comment: We use Angular, and I ask developers to add names or IDs to relevant generated elements 9or do it myself). Selenium webdriver has no problem finding them, so not sure what is your problem.

Comment: @HelpingHands http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/customelements/

Comment: @PeterMasiar I don't have control or influence over the codebase

Comment: Re: "but what if the elements aren't known?". Can you give an example?

Comment: @dzieciou retracted that question

Answer (score 3):

You can find custom elements by using the tagName;

Example of how to find an element that looks like this:

```
<iframe src="..."></iframe>
```

would be

```
WebElement frame = driver.findElement(By.tagName("iframe"));
```

Full documentation is available on the [Selenium API](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp)

I would also suggest you maintain a separate list (or Enum) of your custom elements as they are dynamically generated so easily changed in the code base which could lead to a high number of tests needing updating.

Comment: Thanks but that still doesn't answer why it's not included in the spec. This is a workaround.

Comment: This example is the official way of finding an element by tag name (custom or otherwise).  I am not quite sure what you mean by it not being in the spec.

Comment: Fair enough, accept that may have not come across clearly. Here's a simple scenario. Navigate to the [custom elements](http://html5-demos.appspot.com/hangouts) example, open a console and type in `document.body.getElementsByTagName("*").length` - you should get 6 returned as the result. Using webdriver, I try

`(def d (execute-script "var n = document.body.getElementsByTagName(\"*\"); return n;"))` and a count on that returns 5. Why is webdriver filtering my results?

Comment: I see what you mean.  I would suggest you post that as a separate question as I am sure someone will know the answer (I don't at this point).  My only thought is n being defined as a base 0 value

Comment: Done http://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/16091/webdriver-auto-filtering-results